# Auto select UIPickerView position

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I'm using one UIPickerView for two textFields. One is Country and another one is Province. The problem that I have now is when I select the Country and go back to Province UIPickerView put the same index position as country!

**Here is the code**

PickerView didSelectedRow event

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

selectedpickerData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pickerData objectAtIndex:row], row];

// Editing Country
if (activePickerField == 1) {
    txtCountry.text = selectedpickerData;
}
// Editing Province
else if (activePickerField == 2) {
    txtProvince.text = selectedpickerData;
}
}
```

Q1: How do I keep the index position for each fields?

Q2: How can I select the first index position of UIPickerView when the textField is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPickerView has method

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

which you can use to select 0 as selected index.

Then for the second question you need to verify that [UITextField text:isEqualToString:@""] and then call method above. That can happen when for example some control resign first responder.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do you assign the selected picker index to the field? I  updated the code. Could you please point that out.

Comment: selectedpickerData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pickerData objectAtIndex:row]]; then you can in your if add when textfield 1 is selected to save selected index to some defined int variable and do the same for the second one